# How to get chrome version using command prompt in windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, command-line, terminal, command-prompt

Is it possible to get version installed chrome version using command prompt in windows?

Tried,

```
 "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -version
 "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --version
 "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -product-version
 "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --product-version
```

When i do that, a browser instance is opening. What flag should I be using to get the version.

I am using Windows 7. Google Chrome version is 67.0.3396.87.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a bug filed about this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=158372

### Original Answer (but see the update below)

What works for me is

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" get Version /value
```

It prints

```
Version=67.0.3396.99
```

surrounded by some blank lines.

There are some other suggestions in the bug comments, like querying the registry.

### Update

Someone from the Chromium team posted this "totally unsupported" batch file in the bug comment thread:

```
@ECHO OFF

:: Look for machine-wide Chrome installs (stable, Beta, and Dev).
:: Get the name, running version (if an update is pending relaunch), and
:: installed version of each.
FOR %%A IN (
    {8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96},
    {8237E44A-0054-442C-B6B6-EA0509993955},
    {401C381F-E0DE-4B85-8BD8-3F3F14FBDA57}) DO (
  reg query HKLM\Software\Google\Update\Clients\%%A /v name /reg:32 2> NUL
  reg query HKLM\Software\Google\Update\Clients\%%A /v opv /reg:32 2> NUL
  reg query HKLM\Software\Google\Update\Clients\%%A /v pv /reg:32 2> NUL
)

:: Look for Chrome installs in the current user's %LOCALAPPDATA% directory
:: (stable, Beta, Dev, and canary).
:: Get the name, running version (if an update is pending relaunch), and
:: installed version of each.
FOR %%A IN (
    {8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96},
    {8237E44A-0054-442C-B6B6-EA0509993955},
    {401C381F-E0DE-4B85-8BD8-3F3F14FBDA57},
    {4ea16ac7-fd5a-47c3-875b-dbf4a2008c20}) DO (
  reg query HKCU\Software\Google\Update\Clients\%%A /v name /reg:32 2> NUL
  reg query HKCU\Software\Google\Update\Clients\%%A /v opv /reg:32 2> NUL
  reg query HKCU\Software\Google\Update\Clients\%%A /v pv /reg:32 2> NUL
)
```

That should probably be seen as the right way to go for the time being.

Comment: Thank you very much for this horrifying workaround.  I hate Chrome.

Answer (score 33):

As of today user4851's is still working. I took a look at his linked bug report and the proposed work around did not work for me anymore.

Anways a new hkey is present in my directory which allows you to query the chrome version without being aware of the actual installation location:

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon" /v version
```

Comment: Beware, this will return the correct version after the first run if the installed Chrome only!

Answer (score 20):

I tried Kilian's answer, however in my case, I was running it against a bunch of machines remotely via a service, so I don't think HKEY_CURRENT_USER was valid:

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

Assuming you know where the exe is, you can try a different approach and read the version property of the exe file:

```
# Powershell
# Older versions install to the 32-bit directory
(Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo

# Newer versions use the 64-bit directory
(Get-Item "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo

ProductVersion   FileVersion      FileName
--------------   -----------      --------
76.0.3809.100    76.0.3809.100    C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

To using it in cmd.exe or via any subprocess calls (python, go os/exec, etc.) you can do,

```
powershell -command "&{(Get-Item 'Absolute\path\to\chrome.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion}"
```

Comment: Had to remove (x86) part in my case

Comment: This is IMHO better than the accepted answer, because it's the only one that works for *any Chrome or Chromium binary*, even if it isn't "the" installed Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @YegorAndrosov, newer versions install to the 64-bit program directory. Updated.

Comment: Using this approach on Win10, I only get `.VersionInfo was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: @lenka_cizkova This is a Powershell script, I got the error you mentioned when using it in cmd.exe. `powershell -command "&{(Get-Item "Absolute\path\to\chrome.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion}"` worked for me from cmd prompt

Comment: @PhaniRithvij Good point! (This important piece of information is missing in the answer...)

Comment: I had to use single quotes round 'Absolute\path\to\chrome.exe' or else I was rebuffed with `Get-Item : a positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files\Google\Chrome...`

Comment: @MartinDorey Good catch, the double quotes around the path was pairing with the double quotes around the entire command. Updated.

Answer (score 4):

Using only commandline utils

```
dir /B/AD "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\"|findstr /R /C:"^[0-9].*\..*[0-9]$"
78.0.3904.97
```

List only directories `/AD` within the Chrome application folder in short form `/B`.

`findstr /R /C:"..."` applies the following regex to the list of directories. The regex matches every foldername starting with a digit `^[0-9]` and ending with ad digit `[0-9]$`.
Between the first and last digit there are any characters `.*` allowed but at least one dot should appear `\.`

Comment: sorry but this method is totally unreliable

Comment: Even this fails: 
`start chrome http://chrome://version'

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use [the rust kitty's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72146280/256305) without having chrome on my path, as:

- from PowerShell:

```
(Get-Command C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe').Version.ToString()
```

- from cmd:

```
powershell -command "(Get-Command C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe').Version.ToString()"
```

Answer (score 3):

[user1425134's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57618035/14748624) worked for me, but if you are allowed to assume that Chrome is part of `%PATH%` (if you can open Command Prompt and type `chrome` to start the browser), then it can be greatly simplified.

From Powershell you can type `(Get-Command "chrome").Version.ToString()`

Or from cmd.exe you can type `powershell -c "(Get-Command "chrome").Version.ToString()"`

(same for Chromium, just replace the command name)

Answer (score 0):

Via Powershell the command is -

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | ? {$_.name -eq 'Google Chrome'} |select Name,Version
```