# learn version of chrome browser via python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a script by using selenium. My problem is when the chrome has been automatically updated, my script is not working. So, my solution is learning the web chrome version (not driver) at the beginning and run the related chrome driver. So on my desktop I will keep all versions and run the correct one. But I could not find a solution to get the version of chrome. I will kindly appreciate the helps! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe call 'google-chrome --version' from python? [call like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python)

Comment: I think it will be solution but anyway I could not find what exactly should I write

Comment: If you are on windows, try this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880917/how-to-get-chrome-version-using-command-prompt-in-windows). Worked for me.

Comment: I should get it via Python, using cmd is a manual step for me. Thank you

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(
    r'wmic datafile where name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" get Version /value',
    shell=True
)
print(output.decode('utf-8').strip())
```

**output**

```
Version=79.0.3945.117
```

Comment: I had missed "print(output.decode('utf-8').strip())" . You are a hero, thanks a lot:)

Comment: @Satish Seems you mastered _subprocess_ module :)

Comment: thanks a lot man ;XX i wrote code: cmd_args = [rf'wmic datafile where name="{chrome_path}".format() get Version /value']   subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, cwd='C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\wbem')   
    but didn't work. and for you worked good.