# How to get Google Chrome version Azure DevOps Command Prompt

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, azure-devops, protractor

How can I use command prompt to get the Chrome version on the vmImage on Azure DevOps pipeline?

Comment: How is this related to Selenium? Searching your question on google yields a few helpful results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880917/how-to-get-chrome-version-using-command-prompt-in-windows

Comment: but I'm trying to know it from inside the pipeline on the virtual machine, not on my local machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below script in `Command line` task:

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" get Version /value
```

Then choose corresponding `vmimage` you want to run.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, now my question is...this is the version installed in the vm right? because on the documentation it says that if im using vmImage: 'windows-2019' it contains this https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md which is Google Chrome version: 77.0.3865.90

Comment: @AlanDíaz, Yeah, it is the latest version in real time while you use this script with hosted agent. For doc or the readme in github, I am letting the team which own the agent source code and document know this, and update it. You are not the first one who found the doc is too old.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Chrome version in Azure Devops with a **Powershell** task containing this code:

```
$chromeVersion = ((Get-Item "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo).ProductVersion
```